# setTargetFragment is depricated PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

I am trying to open a `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` from my `PreferenceFragmentCompat` by doing this:

```
@Override
public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
    // check if dialog is already showing
    if (getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
        return;
    }

    final DialogFragment f;

    if (preference instanceof NumberPickerPreference) {
        f = NumberPickerPreferenceDialogFragment.newInstance(preference.getKey());
    } else if (preference instanceof TextAutoCompletePreference) {
        f = TextAutoCompletePreferenceDialogFragment.newInstance(preference.getKey());
    } else
        f = null;

    if (f != null) {
        f.setTargetFragment(this, 0); // This is depricated
        f.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    } else {
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
    }
}
```

But apparently `setTargetFragment` is depricated.

I tried to replace it with this:

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("requestKey", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String s, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

            }
        });
```

but this is crashing the app with

```
Target fragment must implement TargetFragment interface
```

I am guessing this is because the `onCreate` of PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat

```
//Decompiled onCreate of PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fragment rawFragment = this.getTargetFragment();
        if (!(rawFragment instanceof TargetFragment)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Target fragment must implement TargetFragment interface");
        } else {
                ....
        }
}
```

What is the correct way to use `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`?

Comment: If you've even checked the source of dialog for yourself and noticed it still uses target fragment you have to keep using it regardless of deprecation until preference library itself is updated and migrates to another solution.

Comment: @hushed_voice Did you solve this issue? I use the androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0 but the exception still occurs.

Comment: @lucius.pl No. I kept it as is for now